# audioタグでmp3ファイルが再生できない

Tags: eclipse, java-ee, servlet, jsf, xhtml

実行環境
eclipse
java 1.8
payaraserver version5
の環境で構築されています。

```
動的webプロジェクト名
｜
｜
｜
src
｜ーmain
   |
    |- java
   |  |
| ーresouces
   |
｜ーwebapp
      　　　｜
　　　｜ーmetainf
　　　｜ーwebinf
　　　｜
　　　sample.mp3
　　　test.xhtml
```

といったデプロイの仕方になっています
コードは次です
test.xhtml->

```
        <:html
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:jsf="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/javax.faces">
        <h:head>
        <title>testページへようこそ</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
        <:audio src="src/sample.mp3" controls="controls">
        </:audio>
        </h:body>
        </:html>
```

アクセスした結果は
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)になり、
インターフェイスは表示されているのですが、再生ボタンが押せないです

mp3ファイルがデプロイできてないのでしょうか
それか認識ができていないのでしょうか
eclipseの仕様上mp3ファイルを認識できないのしょうか
sftpとかで通したりしないとデプロイはできないのでしょうか

ご回答よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 1):

端的な回答としては、xhtml ファイル中で指定している `src` の指定を `src/sample.mp3` から `sample.mp3` に変更することで期待する動作になるのでは、ということになります。

---

Payara には [`DefaultServlet`](https://javadoc.io/doc/fish.payara.extras/payara-embedded-all/5.193.1/org/apache/catalina/servlets/DefaultServlet.html) が組み込まれ[デフォルト設定](https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/d4bbe3f/appserver/admin/gf_template/src/main/resources/config/default-web.xml#L454-L458)ではこれを利用するような設定が為されているようなので、特に追加の設定を行わずとも静的リソースを応答できるようです。

`src/main/webapp/sample.mp3` にファイルを置いているのであれば、 `http://localhost:8080/<your-app-name>/smaple.mp3` でアクセスできると思います。
次のコマンド

```
curl --head http://localhost:8080/<your-app-name>/smaple.mp3
```

をコマンドプロンプト上(等)で実行し、 `200 OK` が返ってくるのを確認してみてください。

実行結果例:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Payara Server  5.2022.1 #badassfish
X-Powered-By: Servlet/4.0 JSP/2.3 (Payara Server  5.2022.1 #badassfish Java/Eclipse Adoptium/17)
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: W/"1314238-1648841686349"
Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Apr 2022 19:34:46 GMT
Content-Length: 1314238
Content-Type: audio/x-mpeg
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

その上で、 `src/main/webapp/test.xhtml` を次のように記述します:

```html
<html
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
>
  <h:head>
    <title>Facelets Hello World</title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <audio controls="controls">
      <source src="sample.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
    </audio>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

---

([コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/88130/88140?noredirect=1#comment99966_88140)を受けて追記)

ウェブブラウザで `http://localhost:8080/<your-app-name>/foo/bar/baz.xhtml` を開いたとき、サーバ側では、 `/foo/bar/baz.xhtml` というリクエストパスに対してどう対応するのかを実装する必要があります。
Payara を含む、Jakarta EE(旧名 Java EE)仕様では、この実装は Servlet という種類のクラスで行うことになっています。

もう少し具体的に言うと、仕様上、本来であれば、

- リクエストが来た時に、`.war` ファイルに含めたリソース `sample.mp3` をレスポンスとして送信する Servlet の実装
- `/src/sample.mp3` というパスのリクエストが来た時に、↑の Servlet で処理するようにマッピングするルール設定

が必要になります。
その上で、設定したルールから外れるリクエストが来た場合の対応は、フレームワーク(今回はPayara)が提供する "*default*" という名前の Servlet が処理することになっています。
(従って *default* Servlet がどういう挙動になるのかは [Payara のマニュアル](https://docs.payara.fish/) に書かれているべきですが、実際には無さそうでした(ので今回はググって実装を探しました)。)

- 参考: [12.1. Use of URL Paths](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#use-of-url-paths) - Jakarta Servlet Specification, 5.0, September 07, 2020

Payaraでは *default* Servlet が静的コンテンツを返す機能を有しているので、前述した明示的な実装/設定は必須ではありません。
ただし、 *default* Servlet を利用するのであれば、*default* Servlet が期待する通りに リソースファイルを配置する/パスと対応付ける 必要があります。

(逆に言えば、 *default* Servlet を利用せず、前述のような Servlet の実装/設定を行えば質問文中の `test.xhtml` のままでも期待通り動作させることは可能です。敢えてそのような実装を行う動機は無いと思いますが。)

> どうして「<source src="sample.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />」これで通るとわかったのですか？

*default* Servlet の自然な実装を考えたとき、そうなっているであろう、というのは、マニュアルに書かれていなくとも/実装を確認せずとも想像できる範囲かと思います。
(少なくとも、質問文にあるような `/src/` 以下にマッピングされる理由は思い浮かびません)

ちなみに、 `.war` ファイルの中にリソースがどう格納されているかは、 [`jar` コマンド](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/tools/jar.html#GUID-51C11B76-D9F6-4BC2-A805-3C847E857867) で見られます:

```
jar tf <your-file>.war
```

実行結果を見ると、最上階層に `sample.mp3` が格納されているのが分かると思います。
であれば、リクエストパスもコンテキストルート直下 `http://localhost:8080/<your-app-name>/smaple.mp3` であろう、というのが自然な発想かと考えます。

> 「curl --head localhost:8080/<your-app-name>/smaple.mp3 をコマンドプロンプト上(等)で実行し、 200 OK が返ってくるのを確認してみてください。」これが何をしているのかもわからないです

ブラウザで `http://localhost:8080/<your-app-name>/smaple.mp3` を開いて確認するのと同じです。
今回は HTTPステータスコードが `200 OK` であることを明確に確認できるように `curl` コマンドを用いて説明しました。

Comment: dewakazuyukiさん前の回答に続き今回もご回答いただきありがとうございます。無事通りました。ただ疑問なのですが「Payara には DefaultServlet が組み込まれデフォルト設定ではこれを利用するような設定が為されているようなので、特に追加の設定を行わずとも静的リソースを応答できるようです。」これはpayaraの仕様のことをいっているということは理解できましたが内容が理解できないのでよければご説明いただきたいです。また「curl --head http://localhost:8080/<your-app-name>/smaple.mp3
をコマンドプロンプト上(等)で実行し、 200 OK が返ってくるのを確認してみてください。」これが何をしているのかもわからないです。そしてどうして「<source src="sample.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />」これで通るとわかったのですか？自分なりに調べましたがわからなかったです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: すばらしい説明ありがとうございます。